# Difficulty getting local time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, utc

I am struggling to understand how to get time series in local time (with DST) from excel file into a pandas timeseries in UTC. I’ve tried various combinations of .localize(), .replace(), .astimezone(), .to_datetime() , all without luck and I feel like I am getting an inconsistent results in situations that should (at least in my mind) be returning the same thing. The example that gets to the heart of the dilemma follows:. I would be grateful if someone could explain why these two sections of code produce different answers. The first of these sections accomplishes what I would like. It seems like the second should do the same, but it doesn’t.

```
In[1]: UTCtz=timezone("UTC")
In[2]: localtz=timezone("US/Central")
In[3]: dt1=datetime.datetime(2016,3,13,1,0,0,0)
In[4]: dt2=datetime.datetime(2016,3,13,3,0,0,0)
In[5]: dt3=localtz.localize(dt1)
In[6]: dt3
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 13, 1, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Central' CST-1 day, 18:00:00 STD>)
In[7]: dt4=localtz.localize(dt2)
In[8]: dt4
Out[8]: datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 13, 3, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Central' CDT-1 day, 19:00:00 DST>)
In[9]: dt3.astimezone(UTCtz)
Out[9]: datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 13, 7, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
In[10]: dt4.astimezone(UTCtz)
Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 13, 8, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

dt1 and dt2 straddle the DST switch and the conversion to UTC is what I was expecting.
Alternatively, here is what I get from the series that I’ve read from excel into a dataframe (column “timeindex”).

```
In[1]: df.iloc[2]["timeindex"]
Out[1]: Timestamp('2016-03-13 01:00:00')
In[2]: df.iloc[3]["timeindex"]
Out[2]: Timestamp('2016-03-13 03:00:00')
In[3]: localtz.localize(df.iloc[2]["timeindex"])
Out[3]: Timestamp('2016-03-13 01:00:00-0600', tz='US/Central')
In[4]: localtz.localize(df.iloc[3]["timeindex"])
Out[4]: Timestamp('2016-03-13 04:00:00-0500', tz='US/Central')
```

The same function calls as before but the utc gap between times increases by an hour !
What is going on here ?

Comment: You know you have `datetime.utcnow()` , right ?

Comment: I just reviewed datetime.utcnow() and I don't see how this provides and answer to my question or issue. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: I'd use it instead of setting the utc timewone..